# How to customize ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Sinatra

Tags: error-handling, sinatra

in my app.rb I have a get `'/posts/:id'` I have implemented a rescue **ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound** but instead of redirecting to the root url it still displays the errors. Is there a way to customize ActiveRecord errors like a custom routing error (`not_found`)

```
not_found do
  slim :not_found
end

get '/posts/:id' do
  begin
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      redirect '/'#or display a view or a flash-notice
  end
    slim :show_post
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sinatra Book recommends](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error) setting an 'error' route and defining the custom error you want to run through it. In your case, it would look something like this

```
error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  redirect '/'
end
```

NOTE: *You will still see the error page with the stack trace as long as your Sinatra application is set to the "Development" Environment.* You can set it to other environment when you run Sinatra:

```
ruby app.rb -e production
```

More on [Sinatra environments here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments).